# Fetch email of configured account in android phone?

Tags: android

I want to fetch the emails of the account configured on my phone.

How can I do that? Are the emails stored in a database or they are fetched at runtime?

Comment: It is undocumented but it is working fine.

Comment: thks and can i get all the specification from the phone or i hava to ask from the user,the specification for emial-of-other account

Comment: you need to ask credentials from the user...

Comment: like port and everything?isn't that stored anywhere when the user configures it?

Comment: you can use port as it is to fetch emails. The only thing you will need is to get username and password from the user. The code you see is the running code...

Comment: actully i was asking about the port of the hosting server

Comment: you need to give it a try and hopefully it will work at your end too. If the problem comes it will the port then you have to do analysis for the port..

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the GET_ACCOUNTS permission and then run this code:

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
   // Check here for the type and name to find the email records.
}
```

Comment: after getting the accounts what should i do fetch the mails from the configured account?

Comment: You either loop on the accounts to find the email accounts via regex or if you want specific accounts you can call the AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType(String type) method instead. For example:
AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google") will return the gmail accounts.

Comment: i think ur not getting my question

Comment: I think you're not getting my answer... :)
Run these lines to see what you get. I believe the first element in the array you will get for calling AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.google"); will be your "account configured on your phone"

Comment: Run the code and see what you get back... The accounts will include your email account. account.name will be your email address, probably on the first element of the array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3404/discussion-between-dennis-and-incrediapp)